# Cache entry but escape dynamic data

Tags: cache

How can I cache an entry, lets say a product card but exclude an dynamic part? Like amount of favorites / Or link to add or remove to favorite.

```
{% set item = craft.shortlist.item(entry.id) %}

{% cache globally using key "product-card-" ~ entry.id until entry.dateUpdated %}

   ...

   {{ entry.title }}

   ...

   // EXCLUDE THIS PART FROM CACHE
   {% if item.inList %}
        <a class="love animating fav" href="{{ item.removeActionUrl }}" data-id="{{ entry.id }}"><i class="icon icon-heart"></i></a>
    {% else %}
        <a class="love animating" href="{{ item.addActionUrl }}" data-id="{{ entry.id }}"><i class="icon icon-heart"></i></a>
    {% endif %}

{% endcache %}
```

In EE CE Cache there you had {exp:ce_cache:escape}. How can I do this in Craft?

**Made a feature request for escaping parts of cache for dynamic data.**

http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7412950-exclude-cache-for-dynamic-data

**PLEASE VOTE :-)**

Answer (score 2):

You would simply not wrap it in `cache` tags. I don't think there's anything like that EE function to specifically exclude parts within the tag. Might be worth a [feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com) though?

```
{% set item = craft.shortlist.item(entry.id) %}

{% cache globally using key "product-card-" ~ entry.id ~ "-1" until entry.dateUpdated %}

    {{ entry.title }}

    ...

{% endcache %}

// EXCLUDE THIS PART FROM CACHE
{% if item.inList %}
    <a class="love animating fav" href="{{ item.removeActionUrl }}" data-id="{{ entry.id }}"><i class="icon icon-heart"></i></a>
{% else %}
    <a class="love animating" href="{{ item.addActionUrl }}" data-id="{{ entry.id }}"><i class="icon icon-heart"></i></a>
{% endif %}

{% cache globally using key "product-card-" ~ entry.id ~ "-2" until entry.dateUpdated %}

    ...

{% endcache %}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It's repeating the cached content in the 2nd part.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that you're using custom keys. These need to be unique, so you have to add unique string to the key for each caching block.

Comment: Ok. that's what i was thinking. But you then end up with a lots of Cached content per entry. Let say you have some more dynamic data. All the cached content gets cluttered in the DB. I've posted a feature request to escape some parts of the cache tough.

Comment: Made a feature request for escaping parts of cache for dynamic data. 
http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7412950-exclude-cache-for-dynamic-data

Comment: Just saw this (I'm the dev for Shortlist) - right now the best option I've seen is to do as @carlcs did and escape the specific dynamic block. I've looked into alternatives and _right_ now, this seems the only way